# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion. iOS, objective c

Tags: ios, type-conversion

I'm getting this error

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to NSString from int
```

but I am not understanding the concept for the following code:

```
int counts;
counts = self.notificationarray.count;
title.text = (@"Notifications %i", counts );
```

Comment: sorry, I've edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
title.text = (@"Notifications %i", counts );
```

with:

```
title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Notifications %i", counts];
```

as the code you have currently isn't doing at all what you wanted. I guess it's assigning a string (`@"Notifications %i"`) to the title text, and then trying to assign an integer (`counts`) next. What you want to do is to create a string with a format and set that as the title text.